# Chainlink Keepers - getting "InvalidConsumer"

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, chainlink

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'
```

**Environment**:

- Hardhat
- Ethers
- VsCode

**Dependencies**:

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter");
require("hardhat-contract-sizer");
require("dotenv").config();
```

**Replicate the error:**

Tests containing `await raffle.performUpkeep([])`- (Chainlink Keepers) break when reaching this line. No solution found so far after several days of research online.

================================================================

**CODE BITS:**

| Making reference to this function in VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol

```
  modifier onlyValidConsumer(uint64 _subId, address _consumer) {
    if (!consumerIsAdded(_subId, _consumer)) {
      revert InvalidConsumer();
    }
    _;
  }
```

================================================================

There is no apparent reason for the test to break as my setup, dependencies and script are in theory identical to the one in the video besides from running all tests succesfully until now.

**Test example returning error**:

```
              it("doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating", async function () {
                  await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                  await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [interval.toNumber() + 1])
                  await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [])
                  //We pretend to be a Chainlink Keeper
                  await raffle.performUpkeep([])
                  await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })).to.be.revertedWith(
                      "Raffle__NotOpen"
                  )
```

================================================================

**Setup**:

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
const { network, getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Raffle", async function () {
          let raffle, VRFCoordinatorV2Mock, raffleEntranceFee, deployer, interval
          const chainId = network.config.chainId

          beforeEach(async function () {
              deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
              await deployments.fixture(["all"])
              raffle = await ethers.getContract("Raffle", deployer)
              VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer)
              raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEntranceFee()
              interval = await raffle.getInterval()
          })
```

================================================================

| Raffle.sol contract snippet were `checkUpkeep()` & `performUpkeep()` are being called

```
    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /*checkData*/
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData*/
        )
    {
        bool isOpen = (RaffleState.OPEN == s_raffleState);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0");
    }

    function performUpkeep(
        bytes calldata /*performData*/
    )
        external
        override
    {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if(!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_raffleState)
            );
        }
        s_raffleState = RaffleState.CALCULATING;

        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }
```

================================================================

How can I fix this error by adding a consumer? What would be the proper steps to follow in this scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for making this. When it comes to stackoverflow and stack exchange ETH, please don't link to an external git repo and tell others to run your test suite. That changes the question from "I have a specific question X" -> "debug me". We don't want to answer "debug me" questions, but we do want to answer "I have a specific question X".

Comment: That error usually means that you have an invalid consumer, and you need to add a consumer. Can you add more information to this (but keep all the information contained in the question)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thank you for the guidance. Where can I find the relevant information to fix the issue and add a valid consumer succesfully, plz?

Comment: What happens when you call the addconsumer function on the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock?

Comment: I tried calling it inside the hardhat console as: ```function addConsumer(uint64 _subId, address _consumer) external override onlySubOwner(_subId)``` which returns ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier``` referring to ```_subId``` (Not sure if I am doing it right).  Also tried to deploy in remix but deployment fails with ```Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)``` but deploys fine on hardhat. Is this what you were asking about?

Comment: No, can you call it in your deploy script?

Comment: managed to fix the error thanks to the help of a contributor on GitHub....Thank you for the follow up

Comment: Could you add how you fixed it below in an answer here? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Patrick, I was unable to solve this so I started the lesson over to see if I can pinpoint what went wrong. Ifc I figure it out I will post the answer for sure :)

Comment: I'm also facing this issue with the new version of "@chainlink/contracts": "0.4.2". Switched to the previous version @"0.4.1" and it started working.

Comment: Can confirm @nikhil that downgrading to `0.4.1` using the following command eliminates the issue:
`npm i @chainlink/contracts@0.4.1`

Comment: As it is confirmed by many that downgrading to 0.4.1 fixes this issue. It just appears to me as a workaround. How do we solve it if we have tp move to higher version of chainlink?

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue as well and the solution for me was..edit your deploy-raffle js using the following steps
1 make the the variable that holds "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock" contract a global variable
2 after the raffle contract is deployed use the below code to add raffle's address as a consumer then you are done..

```
if (chainId == 31337) {
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId.toNumber(), raffle.address)
    }
```

Comment: For anyone writing tests for lesson 14, you can add the following lines to `02-deploy-random-ipfs-nft.js` after deploying the random IPFS contract to eliminate any `InvalidConsumer` errors:

`if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
     vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId.toNumber(), randomIPFSNFT.address     )  }`

Answer (score 4):

as done manually for testnet (Look into https://youtu.be/rdJ5d8j1RCg by chainlink)
, we have to create a VRFCoordinatorV2 (VRFCoordinatorV2Mock in case of local testing), fund it and then have to add our contract to allowedConsumers list.

Following code we should add after deploying our raffle smart contract

```
if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, raffle.address);

    log('Consumer is added');
  }
```

Comment: Here the issue is that we should be adding our smartcontract as the consumer to the chainLink vrfCoordinator.
We do the same through GUI:

Creation of vrfCoordinator (Only required for local testing, on test-net this is already provided by the chainlink)
Creation of subscription
Addition of your smart contract to the consumers list (Only after this, our smartcontract can use requestRandomWords)
When doing this programatically, we have to add the above code after we deploy our raffle smart contract

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it was obvious for everyone else, but these answers above would most likely throw an err vrfCoordinatorV2Mock is not defined, and to make sure you go through no other errors, i decided to make it as easy as it can get for anyone else with this problem in Patrick Collins' course.
Right below the code that deploys your raffle contract which is

```
const raffle = await deploy("Raffle", {
    from: deployer,
    args: arguments,
    log: true,
    waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
  });
```

paste the following and you should be good to go

```
  if (chainId == 31337) {
    const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
      "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock"
    );
    await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId.toNumber(), raffle.address)
    log("adding consumer...")
    log("Consumer added!")
}
```

You can use chainId or

```
if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. And I have checked what Patrick said about creating a new costumer. It should have been created when running the .createSubscription on the Deploy function, no ?

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {

```
const { deploy, log, get } = deployments;
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
const chainId = network.config.chainId;

const VRF_SUBS_FUND_AMT = ethers.utils.parseEther('30');

let vrfCoordinatorV2address, subsId;
if (devChains.includes(network.name)) {
    const VRFCordinator = await ethers.getContract('VRFCoordinatorV2Mock');
    vrfCoordinatorV2address = VRFCordinator.address;
    //Create a subscription using the mock
    **const txResponse = await VRFCordinator.createSubscription();**
    const txReceipt = await txResponse.wait(1);
    subsId = txReceipt.events[0].args.subId;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. After debugging the code, I found we have to add the Raffle contract's address to VRFCoordinatorV2Mock's consumers by add the following code to your deploy file (for me it is 01-deploy-raffle.js):

```
if (chainId == 31337) {
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId.toNumber(), raffle.address)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet:
**Make sure the below variables used should be global

1. vrfcoordinator_mock_contract
2. subscriptionId**

Make changes soon after deploying Raffle contract

```
    try{
        log("1) DEPLOYING CONTRACT --**-- ")
        const raffle_contract = await deploy("Raffle",{
            from: deployer,
            args: arguments,
            log: true,
            blockConfirmations: network.config.waitConfirmations
        })
        log("2) CONTRACT DEPLOYED --**-- ")

        /* Adding Raffle as consumer to VRFCoordinatorV2Mock*/
        if(developmentChain.includes(network.name)){
            log("3) Adding Raffle as consumer to VRFCordinatorV2Mock")
            /* add consumer */
            const raffle_consumer_contract = await ethers.getContract("Raffle")
            const consumer_addressRaffle = raffle_consumer_contract.address
            try{
                await vrfcoordinator_mock_contract.addConsumer(subscriptionId,consumer_addressRaffle)
            }
            catch(error){
                log(error)
            }
        }
        /* Finally verifying Contract if not on development chain*/
        if(!developmentChain.includes(network.name) && (process.env.GOERLI_ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || process.env.POLYGON_ETHERSCAN_API_KEY)){
            console.log("3) VERIFYING CONTRACT --**-- ")
            const contractRaffleAddress = raffle_contract.address
            await verifyRaffle(contractRaffleAddress,arguments)
            console.log("4) CONTRACT VERIFIED --**-- ")
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        log(`Error Deploying Raffle ... ${error}`)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue and i solve by downgrade the chainlink package version, use below command to solve this issue .

```
yarn add --dev @chainlink/contracts@0.4.1
```